# Автопостинг в социальные сети

Tags: php, google-api, соцсети, одноклассники, google-plus

Есть ли в Google+ и Одноклассники API, позволяющий постить в группы?

C ВКонтакте разобрался — после модерации посты автоматом постятся в группу вместе с картинкой, хэш-тегами и ссылкой на сайт (также скрипт анализирует последний добавленный пост и отложенный пост — таким образом, всё постится равномерно и постинг может быть, например, каждые 4 часа).

С Twitter'ом всё понятно.

У Facebook один минус — токен на 60 дней, но жить с этим можно ;)

Интересуют Google+ и Одноклассники: у них я не нашёл этого. Если я ошибаюсь — дайте ссылку на документацию.

Может у кого есть альтернативные решения для этих сетей?

Хотелось бы сделать как в VK (я принимаю в группе минимум участия).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как в тегах указан и **PHP**, покажу небольшой класс который я написал для похожих целей, он не идеален, но работает, и из него можно допилить что угодно.)

**Пример использования :**

```
new OK([
    'username' => 'логин',
    'password' => 'пароль',
    'path' => 'ссылка на группу',
    'post_link' => 'ссылка которую нужно постить'
]);
```

**Сам Класс :**

```
class OK
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $path;
    public $post_link;
    public $browser = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36';

    public $auth_hash;

    public $cookie;

    public $response;

    private $__group_id;
    private $__tkn;
    private $__gwt;
    private $path_info;

    public function __construct($params)
    {
        foreach($params as $key => $value)
        {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }

        if(filter_var($this->path, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED))
        {
            $path = parse_url($this->path);

            $this->path = $path['path'];
        }

        $this->path = '/' . trim($this->path, '/');

        if($this->test_auth())
        {
            $this->cookie = $this->auth_hash;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->cookie = $this->login();
        }

        if(!$this->cookie)
        {
            return $this->say('php.loginError');
        }

        $this->path_info = $this->path_info($this->path, $this->cookie);

        if(!is_array($this->path_info))
        {
            if($this->path_info)
            {
                return $this->say($this->path_info);
            }
            else
            {
                if(isset($this->__group_id) and isset($this->__tkn) and isset($this->__gwt))
                {
                    $this->join_group();

                    $this->path_info = $this->path_info($this->path, $this->cookie);

                    if(!is_array($this->path_info))
                    {
                        return $this->say('php.groupErrorAfterJoin');
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return $this->say('php.groupError');
                }
            }
        }

        $post = $this->post();

        if($post)
        {
            if($post === true)
            {
                return $this->say('posted');
            }
            else
            {
                return $this->say($post);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->say('php.undefinedPostError');
        }
    }

    private function say($response)
    {
        $this->response = $response;
    }

    private function join_group()
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->browser);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '1=1');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'JSESSIONID=' . $this->cookie);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('TKN: ' . $this->__tkn));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.odnoklassniki.ru' . $this->path . '?cmd=LeftColumnTopCardAltGroup&st.cmd=altGroupMain&st.directLink=on&st.groupId=' . $this->__group_id . '&st.altGroup.action=groupJoin&st._aid=LBAID_UCM_AltGroupTopCardButtonsJoin_altGroupMain&gwt.requested=' . $this->__gwt . '&p_sId=');

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return;
    }

    private function link_preview()
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->browser);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'linkUrl=' . $this->post_link . '&LinkPreviewId=5.linkPreview');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'JSESSIONID=' . $this->cookie);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('TKN: ' . $this->path_info['tkn']));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.odnoklassniki.ru' . $this->path . '?cmd=LinkPreview&gwt.requested=' . $this->path_info['gwt'] . '&st.cmd=altGroupMain&st.directLink=on&st.groupId=' . $this->path_info['group_id']);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        preg_match('!style="display: none" class="data-with-image_i" src="([^"]*)"!', $response, $thumb);
        preg_match('!,"7":"([^"]*)",!', $response, $title);
        preg_match('!,"8":"([^"]*)",!', $response, $description);
        preg_match('!,"11":"([^"]*)"!', $response, $url);

        if(!$thumb[1] or !$title[1] or !$url[1])
        {
            return;
        }

        return '{"linkData":{"title":"'.$title[1].'", "description":"'.$description[1].'", "providerViewer":"1;1", "sourceUrl":"'.$url[1].'", "thumbnail":"'.$thumb[1].'", "movieId":0}}';
    }

    private function post()
    {
        $link_preview = $this->link_preview();

        if(!$link_preview)
        {
            return 'php.noLinkPreview';
        }

        $form_data = '{"formType":"Group", "postDataList":[' . $link_preview . '], "news":false, "toStatus":false}';

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->browser);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'st.status.postpostForm=' . $this->path_info['form_id'] . 
                                             '&st.status.postgroupId=' . $this->path_info['group_id'] .
                                             '&postingFormData=' . urlencode($form_data));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'JSESSIONID=' . $this->cookie);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('TKN: ' . $this->path_info['tkn']));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.odnoklassniki.ru' . $this->path . '?cmd=MediaTopicPost&gwt.requested=' . $this->path_info['gwt'] . '&st.cmd=altGroupMain&st.directLink=on&st.groupId=' . $this->path_info['group_id'] . '&p_sId=');

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        if(empty($response))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(strpos($response, '"status":"ok"') !== false)
        {
            return true;
        }

        preg_match('!"errorCodeValue":"([^"]*)"!', $response, $error);

        if($error[1])
        {
            return $error[1];
        }

        return false;
    }

    private function path_info($path, $cookie)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->browser);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'true=true');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'JSESSIONID=' . $cookie);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.odnoklassniki.ru' . $path);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        if(strpos($response, 'HTTP/1.1 404 ') !== false)
        {
            return 'php.groupRemoved';
        }

        if(strpos($response, 'Location: http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/dk?st.cmd=altGroupRestricted') !== false)
        {
            return 'php.userBlocked';
        }

        preg_match('!state:"st\.cmd=altGroupMain&amp;st\.groupId=([^"]*)"!', $response, $group_id);
        preg_match('!,"s2":"([^"]*)",!', $response, $form_id);
        preg_match('!TKN: (.*?)$!m', $response, $tkn);
        preg_match('!,gwtHash:"([^"]*)",!', $response, $gwt);
        preg_match('!<\!--{"gId":"([^"]*)",!', $response, $id);

        if(!$group_id[1] or !$tkn[1] or !$gwt[1] or empty($group_id[1]) or empty($tkn[1]) or empty($gwt[1]))
        {
            return false;
        }

        $this->__gwt = $gwt[1];
        $this->__tkn = $tkn[1];
        $this->__group_id = $group_id[1];

        if(!$form_id[1] or empty($form_id[1]) or !$id[1] or empty($id[1]))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return array('group_id' => $group_id[1], 'form_id' => $form_id[1], 'tkn' => $tkn[1], 'gwt' => $gwt[1], 'id' => $id[1]);
    }

    private function login()
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->browser);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'st.email='.urlencode($this->username).'&st.password='.urlencode($this->password).'&st.redirect=/ok&st.posted=set&st.screenSize=&st.screenSize=&st.browserSize=&st.flashVer');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/dk?cmd=AnonymLogin&st.cmd=anonymLogin&tkn='.mt_rand());

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        if(!preg_match('!Location: http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/ok!', $response)) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        preg_match('!JSESSIONID=([^;]*);!', $response, $cookie);

        if(!$cookie[1] or empty($cookie[1]))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return $cookie[1];
    }

    private function test_auth()
    {
        if(!$this->auth_hash)
        {
            return false;
        }

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'JSESSIONID=' . $this->auth_hash);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ok.ru/settings');

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        if(strpos($response, 'HTTP/1.1 302') !== false)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    static function auth($username, $password)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'st.email='.urlencode($username).'&st.password='.urlencode($password).'&st.redirect=/ok&st.posted=set&st.screenSize=&st.screenSize=&st.browserSize=&st.flashVer');

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/dk?cmd=AnonymLogin&st.cmd=anonymLogin&tkn='.mt_rand());

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        if(!preg_match('!Location: http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/ok!', $response)) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        preg_match('!JSESSIONID=([^;]*);!', $response, $cookie);

        if(!$cookie[1] or empty($cookie[1]))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return $cookie[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: дайте пример использования этого класса для чайника